# query with distinct and order by

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have this data set

```
Id      TypeId      Description
-------------------------------
1       1           happy
2       1           sad
3       2           sad
4       2           sad
5       3           upset
6       1           upset
7       2           chilaxing
8       4           happy
```

And I am trying to get LINQ to do this:

```
select count(Id) as count, Type from MyDate
group by Description
order by count desc
```

So I get:

```
count   Type
------------
3       sad
2       happy
2       upset
1       chilaxing
```

But nothing I am trying is working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from d in data
group d by d.description into g
orderby g.Count()  desc
select new {g.Key, Count = g.Count()}
```

Comment: well wen you do it like that it seems obvious :)